# How to overwrite meta robots?

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm having an issue with changing the meta tag on category pages from:

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
```

To:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

I tried adding the following XML in Layout updates of the category:

```
<head><meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/></head>
```

I flushed cache, but no luck. Any ideas?
The current results is that the meta tag has the old value:

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">
```

I tried the XML on a CMS page and it's working fine. Magento version is 2.1.10.

Comment: Which XML file did you use? I tried your code and it worked for me when I added it to `catalog_category_view.xml`.

Comment: I tried it directly in the admin-> Products-> Categories-> Design-> Layout Update XML. BTW, what Magento version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.3. I just tried adding it via admin (in the "Design" tab) and it worked there as well. **Edit**: I also refreshed the following cache types: Configuration, Layouts, Page Cache.

Comment: It looks like it's related to the magento version, and not code related.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of the module loading order (since it works for cms pages).
If you want to manipulate / extend given layout handles like for example catalog_category_view you have to correctly set the module sequence for your module.

If you do not set the sequence, it's more or less random if your change to the layout will work or not.

The module sequence defines the order of which layout files (besides other configurations) can override other layout xml files.

So if you want to make a change to the catalog_category_view layout, you need to set a module sequence for the Magento_Catalog module in your module, to ensure, that your change is applied after the Magento_Catalog changes / additions.

e.g. /etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Brandung_Seo" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

After setting the module sequence in your module, you have to execute bin/magento setup:upgrade for example, which will update the module loading order (persisted in app/etc/config.php)

the layout xml file should look like this

catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

(example: https://github.com/brandung/magento2-module-seo)

Comment: When you say "If you want to manipulate / extend given layout handles like for example catalog_category_view you have to correctly set the module sequence for your module." to what module are you refering to? Just to be clear, I find your solution useful for other cases when you're actually creating a module, but in this case, we are talking about default magento...